# Is triangle congruence considered as theorems or postulates?

Tags: triangles, congruences-geometry

Is triangle congruence like $SSS$, $SAS$, $ASA$ and $AAS$ considered as theorems or postulates?
I've seen some people calling it as theorems and some other people calling it as postulates. What I know about theorems and postulates is that theorems needs to be proven and postulates are like basic assumptions taken to be true. They're 2 different things.

And I know Euclid only gave 5 postulates, so if this is considered as postulate then that would make it 6. (I'm not sure)

Also if this is considered as theorems, that means that it must be proven to be true. Does that mean that I can find proofs for this? (If so, please let me know where I can find it)

Comment: I would say you can prove them fairly easily by drawing sketches of each, extending the lengths / angles and showing that there is only one possibility of created triangle, that triangle being the same. If your definition of a triangle is written solely in terms of the three sides (A, B, C) and three angles accompanying them (a, b, c), basic rules like the sine rule for area can easily prove SSS by contradiction, etc, as a criterion for congruence is that all basic properties like area, volume, etc are the same.

Comment: These things come down to choices of axiom system.  Euclid's congruence proofs don't really follow from the axioms presented there.  Hilbert's system makes SAS into an explicit axiom...I'd say that was the most popular modern approach.

Comment: While really pioneering, Euclid was still abit imprecise regarding axiomatics. In Hilbert's axioms of Euclidean geometry, one of the axioms is SAS (the other congruences are then theorems)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen sorry, who is Hilbert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going by class 8 ncert book, SAS congruence rule is considered as an axiom while SSS, ASA and AAS are theorems which are proved by contradiction as well as SAS. You can go through the pdf [here](https://ncert.nic.in/textbook/pdf/iemh107.pdf) and read the proofs too

Comment: did Hilbert come up with that (SAS is an axiom)?

Comment: Sorry I don't have any idea who Hilbert is @Mohammadmuazzamali

Comment: David Hilbert the famous German mathematician